# How to set status code from service layer in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, response, http-status-codes

I have a service that is helping me to validate some forms. I want to set HTTP status code from inside of it when it finds that form is actually invalid.

Is it OK to do so? How do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do that (probably there's lot more solutions) is throwing some (custom) exception in your service in case your form is invalid.

Then I would create an [exception listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) which would listen on kernel exception event. Configuration of such listener would look something like this (`services.yml`)

```
kernel.listener.your_listener:
    class: Acme\Your\Namespace\YourExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onException }
```

And than your `onException` method in `YourExceptionListener` class:

```
public function onException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();
    if ($exception instanceof YourCustomExceptionInterface) {
        $response = new Response('', 400);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

This way you get nicely decoupled stuff, and your form validation service is independent of response.

Comment: Thanks! It makes perfect sense )

Comment: And what if I need to actually return some data from the server? Do I add all the data to the exception instance and retrieve it later in exception listener to create a response?

Comment: yep, this might be the solution